# Powershell script in WIX msi Installer

Tags: xml, powershell, wix, installation

Could you please advise how could I call Power-Shell script for the npm install and some other actions using the WiX MSI installer.

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
 xmlns:powershell="http://schemas.gardiner.net.au/PowerShellWixExtensionSchema">
<?include Variables.wxi?>
<Product Id="$(var.ProductCode)" 
       Name="$(var.ProductName)" 
       Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.1" 
       Manufacturer="$(var.Manufacturer)"
       UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)">

    <Package InstallerVersion="200" 
             Compressed="yes" 
             InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <Component Id="NpmInstallMain.ps1" Guid="e11556a2-e066-4393-af5c-9c9210187eba"  DiskId="1" Directory="INSTALLLOCATION">
      <File Id="NpmInstallMain.ps1" Name="NpmInstall.ps1" Source="$(var.SourceFolder)\NpmInstall.ps1"/>
    </Component>

    <Property Id="POWERSHELLEXE">
      <RegistrySearch Id="POWERSHELLEXE"
                      Type="raw"
                      Root="HKLM"
                      Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell"
                      Name="Path" />
    </Property>

    <Condition Message="This application requires Windows PowerShell.">
      <![CDATA[Installed OR POWERSHELLEXE]]>
    </Condition>

    <SetProperty Id="RunStartScript"
             Before ="RunStartScript"
             Sequence="execute"
             Value="&quot;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe&quot; -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -InputFormat None -NoProfile -File &quot;[INSTALLDIR]/NpmInstall.ps1&quot;" />

    <CustomAction Id="RunStartScript" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixQuietExec" Execute="immediate" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="RunStartScript" Before="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed OR UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
    <UI>
        <ProgressText Action="NpmInstallMain">PowerShell Files (elevated)</ProgressText>
    </UI>
</Product>
```

How could I define the cause of the issue? I tried to log the errors using the console

```
msiexec /i CustomInstaller.msi /l*v MyLogFile.txt
```

But it gives not so much useful information

```
Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1708 
Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1709
```

Comment: Which issue do you have actually?

Comment: I have prepared the installer using WiX. It works pretty well without the code above.
But when I am trying to add the execution of the PowerShell script it fails.
Could you please advise what can be the cause of the issue or at least how to define it?

Comment: As well as I tried to use 

    <powershell:File Id="NpmInstallFile" File="[#NpmInstall.ps1]" />
  But I have the same result.

Comment: While this may or may not be part of the problem, custom actions that change the state of the system should be scheduled as "deferred" custom actions. Your custom action is scheduled to run "immediate". See `Execute="immediate"`.